# SFTP automation Using WinSCP or FileZilla

Tags: automation, sftp, file-transfer, filezilla, winscp

So, as part of my daily jobs, I have to transfer a one file from our customers server to our internal server and any responses back.
Each customer effectively has one file up and one file down each day.

I have an SFTP server here that I can use and is already used manually for a few sites.
I'm looking to automate as many sites as possible using batch files on a scheduled task.

Initially, I'm looking at automating the internal side of the process.

We simple have a requests folder that needs to import from the SFTP (then delete the original on the SFTP) and a response folder which needs to copy to a 'sent' folder and then export to the SFTP (also, deleteing the original)

On the SFTP server I have a "to site" and "from site" folder. Each file is site specific followed by a variable. So `SiteNameImport.<variable>` and `SiteNameExport.<variable>`

EDIT:
I'm asking this as I'm a novice at scripting and basically have no idea what to do.
I've tried reading the automation guide on WinSCP website but a lot of it means nothing to me.

Comment: You can do this using WinSCP (not using FileZilla, it does not have any scripting interface). See WinSCP [automation guide](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation). Though you did not specify what particular problem you are facing.

Answer (score 2):

Filezilla doesn't support automation, You're better off with WinSCP. They have some scripting examples [here](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library) as well as any other information you'll need to build the scripts functionality. You'll just need to add the specifics (Like deleting sent files and so on) CuteFTP is also another solution you can script with but I believe you have to pay for a licence. I suggest VBscript, Examples can be found [Here](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_com_wsh#vbscript) for vbscript.